# Do I need firebase rules if I'm using server-side?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, server-side

Do I need to modify the code in firebase rules if I'm using server-side using nodejs

I set the rules as follows:

```
allow read, write: if true;
```

is there any problem ? Note that I do not use firebase on the client side

Answer (score 1):

Backend code using the server/admin SDKs that are initialized with a service account always bypasses security rules completely, as if they don't exist.  Rules only apply to web and mobile apps.  If you don't need frontend access at all, set your rules to reject everything for maximum security.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions):

> The server client libraries bypass all Cloud Firestore Security Rules and instead authenticate through Google Application Default Credentials. If you are using the server client libraries or the REST or RPC APIs, make sure to set up Identity and Access Management (IAM) for Cloud Firestore.

Comment: I am using (firebase SDK) on the server, is it a problem if I don't reject the rules

Comment: With the rule you showed, that allows anyone on the internet to read and write all data in the matching collection.  You can decide if that's a problem.

Comment: The Admin SDKs bypass the security rules. So if you only want your server-side code (e.g. using the Admin SDK) to be able to access Firestore, you should reject all access in your rules (so `if false`). That way all non-Admin SDK access will be rejected by the rules, while the Admin SDK bypasses those rules anyway and thus have access.